# Allow edits from different users appear in different color inside memo box : Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a memo field which contains rich text. I am able to identify a user and change all the text in the box instead of just the text they added.

I am looking to write code which allows the text to be edited and after update , the edited text will appear a different color than the original text in the memo field.

[image]

I have tried :

```
Dim strNew As String
Dim strOld As String

 If Me.txt_username_id = "grant" Then

 strOld = Me.Form!txtnotesaboutproduct1.OldValue.ForeColor = vbBlack<br/>
 strNew = Me.Form!txtnotesaboutproduct1.ForeColor = vbRed

End If
```

I have also tried

---

```
Dim ctlOld As TextBox<br/>

Set ctlOld = Me.Form!txtnotesaboutproduct1

If Me.txt_username_id = "grant" Then
    ctlOld = Me.Form!txtnotesaboutproduct1.OldValue.ForeColor = vbRed

End If
```

Comment: great! would you edit your question and include your code?

Comment: my attempts have been added to the question

Comment: Interesting question, but this won't be easy. `.ForeColor` will be (I think) of no use - you need to work with the underlying HTML. Identify the changes, put a `<span color=xyz>` around them. Or so.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I do this with a continuous subform for Notes, so that I can hold the data, date and user, rather than just one formatted text box. Though I do realize this might be a lot more real estate that you might have, you can use a conditional format within the subform. I do agree that if it is possible, you'll likely need to use HTML and not .Forecolor, which will change the entire box.